# How to show two sets are either open or closed in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $ \mathbb{Q} $, obtained as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $A=(-1,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $B=(\sqrt-2 , \sqrt2)\cap \mathbb{Q}$.  Are A and B open in $\mathbb{Q}$ or closed?

I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither open nor closed in $\Re$.  How can I start my proof?

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb Q$ is open and closed in $\mathbb Q$. That is the question, not whether $\mathbb Q$ is open or closed in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: As a start -- what is your definition of induced topology? (i.e., what are the opens of $\mathbb{Q}$, with regard to those of $\mathbb{R}$?)

Answer (score 0):

Given $x\in A=(-1,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, we know that $(-1,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so there exists $\delta$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $y\in(-1,1)$, for $y\in\mathbb{R}$. The same $\delta$ works for $\mathbb{Q}$: If $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $d(x,y)<\delta$, then $y\in(-1,1)$ and, by hypothesis, $y\in\mathbb{Q}$, so $y\in A$. Therefore $A$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now look at the proof above and let's forget that we are working with $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, and $(-1,1)$. You should be able to prove the following result, basically copying the arguments above:

**Proposition:** Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $N$ a subset of $M$ endowed with the restricted metric. If $U$ is open in $M$, then $U\cap N$ is open in $N$.

Using this proposition, it then becomes clear that $B$ is also open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now let's try to verify if $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$. We know that $(-1,1)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, because $1\in\overline{(-1,1)}\setminus(-1,1)$ (in $\mathbb{R}$). The same holds for $\mathbb{Q}$: For any $\delta>0$, we can find a ratinal number $q\in(-1,1)$ with $d(q,1)<\delta$ (here, use density of $\mathbb{R}$), this means that $1$ is in the closure (in $\mathbb{Q}$) of $A$, but not in $A$, which is therefore not closed.

For $B$, we take complements: The complement of $B$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{C}=([\sqrt{2},\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q})\cup((-\infty,-\sqrt{2}]\cap\mathbb{Q})$. But $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, so $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{C}=((\sqrt{2},\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q})\cup((-\infty,-\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q})$. Since $(\sqrt{2},\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, the proposition above implies $(\sqrt{2},\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$, and similarly for $(-\infty,-\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}$, therefore $\mathbb{Q}\setminus B$ is a union of two open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$, so $\mathbb{Q}\setminus B$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$, and therefore $B$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ (as well as being open).